# Get list of lists without recursion

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to get all lists with length 4 from alphabet [0..9] with unique elements.

```
allNumbers = [a | let list = [0..9], x1 <- list, x2 <- list, x3 <- list, x4 <- list, let a = [x1,x2,x3,x4], nub a == a]
```

How can I get some simplest and nicest version of that? What if I need all such lists with length 10 (I don't want to copypasting x# <- list 10 times)? Non-recursive answer is encouraged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `sequence`:

```
Prelude> let a = [0..9]
Prelude> sequence $ replicate 4 a
```

This relies on the monad instance for list.
Then you can add in the `nub` part with `filter`:

```
filter (\x -> nub x == x) $ sequence $ replicate 4 [0 .. 9]
```

---

Update:  as pointed out in a comment, you could also use `replicateM` (which I was not aware of):

```
Prelude> :m + Control.Monad
Prelude> filter (\x -> nub x == x) $ replicateM 4 [0 .. 9]
```

Comment: Will there be duplicate results? IF so, and you don't want them, add `nubBy (\x -> sort x == x) $ ...`

Comment: @trinithis -- good point, but I'm not sure what the OP wants.

Comment: `replicateM n = sequence . replicate n`

Comment: Remember that you can always search for functions by their type using [Hoogle](http://haskell.org/hoogle/) -- if you didn't know about `replicateM` but you suspected there was such a function that took an `Int` plus an `m a` and returned an `m [a]`, you could [search for it](http://haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=Monad+m+%3D%3E+Int+-%3E+m+a+-%3E+m+[a]) and Hoogle would say "Why yes, there is such a function, here you go!"